# How to retrieve selection from dynamically created listboxes with variable names

Tags: c#, winforms

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    if(ctrl is ListBox)
    {
        string selectedtext = ctrl.GetItemText(ctrl.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Getting the following message

> Control does not contain a definition for "GetItemText" and no extention method for "SelectedItem"

Listboxes are created with the name `LTBitemXX`

Comment: Assign a name to the control when creating. Then find it simply. `var listBox = this.Controls.Find("someName", true).OfType<ListBox>().FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

The `ctrl` variable is declared of type `Control`, so you can't use anything specific to a derived class.

Something like this would work though:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    ListBox lb = ctrl as ListBox;
    if(lb != null)
    {
        string selectedtext = lb.GetItemText(lb.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also get fancy with the new pattern matching and use `if (ctrl is ListBox lb){ string selectedtext = lb.GetItemText(lb.SelectedItem); }`

Comment: Ooo... so fancy!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
   if(ctrl is ListBox)
   {
       string selectedtext = ((ListBox)ctrl).GetItemText(ctrl.SelectedItem);
   }
}
```

You can also use Linq to get the controls of the specified type

```
foreach (ListBox listbox in Controls.OfType<ListBox>())
{
   string selectedtext = listbox.GetItemText(listbox.SelectedItem);
}
```